# Can't catch Angular 8 variable change

Tags: angular, observable

Good morning, 
I'm developing a simple (for now) app in Angular to train myself, but I can't seem to catch a variable change in a service.
What I mean is that I have a component subscribing a variable from a service, but when the variable in the service gets updated, the variable in the component does not.

My component:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AnswersService } from "./answers.service";

export class AnswersComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  hours = [];

  constructor(private answersService: AnswersService) {
    this.answersService.hours.subscribe(value => {
      this.hours = value; // value doesn't get changed
      console.log(value); // never gets logged
    });
  }

  // ... then i use the this.hours variable down below
}
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from '../../../server.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AnswersService implements OnInit {

  constructor(private server: ServerService) { }
  hours = new Subject<any[]>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHours(); // on init i get the new data
  }

  private getHours() { // when this happens, my Subject should be updated
      this.hours.next(['03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '02:00']);
  }
}
```

The expected behaviour in my component is that hours is initially an empty array but after the database request is fulfilled it should become that long array of strings you see in the service.

What have I not understood correctly? Many guides/StackOverflow answers I've tried do the same things I've tried, so I don't understand where is the problem.

---

EDIT: like it was suggested, I moved the method invocation for the update from the onInit (that does not work properly with services) to the constructor. Also, i changed it from Subject to BehaviorSubject.

The problem, now is that if I want to assign it data taken from a database, it does not update anymore.

```
private getHours() {
  this.server.getExperiment({id:1}).then((response: any) => {
    // Just a simple endpoint I've set for this time
    this.hours.next(['03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '02:00']);
  });
}
```

The getExperiment is implemented as:

```
private async request(method: string, url: string, data?: any) {
  const result = this.http.request(method, url, {
    body: data,
    responseType: 'json',
    observe: 'body'
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    result.subscribe(resolve, reject);
  });
}

getExperiment(experiment) {
  return this.request('GET', `http://localhost:8080/experiment/${experiment.id}`);
}
```

Following a comment I've tried editing it (producing the same result) as:

```
private request(method: string, url: string, data?: any) {
  return this.http.request(method, url, {
    body: data,
    responseType: 'json',
    observe: 'body'
  });
}
```

So that I can subscribe instead of waiting for a Promise:

```
private getHours() {
  this.server.getExperiment({id:1}).subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.hours.next(['03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '02:00']);
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you try to move this.getHours() to the subscription. NgOnInit on a service is not common. see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23235

Comment: Uhm, sorry but what do you mean by moving it in the subscription? Is it the same as "in the constructor", and the component stays the same?

Comment: Like Marcel stated, ngOnInit isn't fired for Angular services, so you'll have to call the `getHours()` from the constructor.  You might consider using a `BehaviorSubject` to retain the last value of the subject.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzw9vg

Comment: I'm sorry where I said subscription I meant move to the constructor of the service of course

Comment: Hi mate, you should try instead of getting you service values in the `constructor` try getting it in an `ngOnInit`. Don't forget to implement it: `export class AnswersComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit` and to import it : `import { OnInit } from '@angular/core`;

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot (the BehaviorSubject was the thing that made it work it seems), but now I have another problem. If in the service the getHours tries to get them from a database, it does not update anymore. I'll update the question

Comment: You should also create a subscription, which you can destroy. Next, you need to pass a default value when you use a BehaviorSubject. Also, how many times do you call getHours()?

Comment: I've passed [] as default value, and getHours() will only get called when the page loads (hence why I thought putting it on NgOnInit was a good idea at first)

Comment: I asume you get back an array from the DB aswell, then you can this.hours.next(reponse). But if I was you, you should subscribe instead of converting it to a promise by using then.

Comment: I understand the difference between a subscription and a promise, but I don't know how to implement them in Angular. At the moment my method returns a Promise of a subscription. Should it be a simple subscription?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that may have my same problem: the solutions adopted in the comments solve it. 
My second problem was an async one, I was not using the subscriber correctly in my component.

Thank for everyone that helped me in the comments.